# Как отправить данные во View?

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, razor

У меня уже настроены связи меджу таблицами, таблицы созданы и в них записи добавляются.
Но не пойму, как во View получать данные из этих таблиц. Когда птаюсь это сделать через слово `Model`, то получаю ошибку: *`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`*. Я новичок в MVC.

**index.cshtml**

```
@model FaqVM
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

@Model.MainCategoryTitle // Ошибка
```

**Faq.cs**

```
public class Faq : CanBeLocalized, IHaveIntegerId, ICanProvideCreatedTime, IHaveConcurrencyToken
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Localize] public string MainCategoryTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string ConcurrencyToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Disabled { get; set; }
    public int SOrder { get; set; } = 0;
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FaqSubcategory> FaqSubcategories { get; set; } = new HashSet<FaqSubcategory>();
}
```

**FaqVM.cs**

```
public class FaqVM
{
    public string MainCategoryTitle { get; set; }
    public List<FaqSubcategory> FaqSubcategories { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View является частью MVC,очевидно в цепочке вывода модели в представление должен быть контроллер. При вызове View из контроллера в нее должна передаваться модель в качестве параметра. Пример тривиального контроллера:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var faq = new FaqVM();
    return View(faq);
}
```

Тогда во View можно будет использовать переданный объект.